# Has Unity got an equivalent to Castles Windsor's facility concept?

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container

Castle Windsor facilities allow you to hook up some custom code that runs whenever components are registered.  Does Unity have an equivalent?

Comment: I don't think so. Why not use Windsor?

Answer (score 1):

Unity interceptors are described in full [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd140045.aspx), but the short answer is no.